# Cannot reinstall Ubuntu

Tags: boot, grub2, windows, reinstall

I've read other fairly similar posts but those situations are different and the solutions don't work at all.

I started with Windows 10 as my only OS. I then tried to install Ubuntu 64 bit as a dual boot alongside windows. It installed but didn't work, everything was crashing. So I went to the disk management tool on Windows (see below):

[pic of my hard disk partitions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/blz9R.png)

My memory of what I did is a bit hazy as I'm new to this and did it about a day ago. Basically, I cleared/formatted or something the stuff that was supposed to be where Ubuntu was. I believe I might have done it more than one of the segments the were shown on the disk management software. Then I extended the size of the Windows partition.

When I try to re install Ubuntu I keep hitting this message from Grub:

[Grub bash like line editing message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9cpD7.jpg)

I thought I should make sure my boot order had USB first. It is. Please help! Thanks.